# How to create two DIFFERENT interactive graphs (bar and line) with same data in one CELL using python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Here's my sample code. However, it only shows a bar graph (user interactive) per cell. I want to add a USER INTERACTIVE LINE GRAPH of a 7-day moving average of the data. How?

```
df_cyp = df_exte[df_exte['location']=='Cyprus']

fig = px.bar(df_cyp, x='date', y='total_cases', template='plotly_dark',
      color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.qualitative.G10,
      labels=dict(date='April 2020 - October 2021', total_cases='Total Confirmed Cases'))

fig.update_layout(font_family='Rockwell')
fig.update_layout(title_text='CYPRUS TOTAL CASES', title_x=0.5)
fig['layout']['title']['font']= dict(size=25)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plotly, I understood that I want to use the subplot setting to draw a bar graph on the left side and a line graph on the right side. Since no data was presented, I used the volume and closing price of stock data as an example to create the code.

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-04-01", end="2021-10-01")

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df['Volume'],
                     name='Volume'),
              secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Close'],
                         mode='lines',
                         name='Close',
                         line=dict(color='green')
                        ),secondary_y=True)
              
fig.update_layout(font_family='Rockwell',
                  title_text='CYPRUS TOTAL CASES',
                  title_x=0.5,
                  title_font=dict(size=25),
                  template='plotly_dark',
                  yaxis_title='Total Confirmed Cases',
                  xaxis_title='April 2020 - October 2021',
                 )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is it user interactive sir?

Comment: Of course, you can zoom and hover.

Answer (score 1):

- simple case of adding a line to your existing bar chart.  Line has been calculated using **pandas** as a moving average
- appears your data is COVID OWID data, so have used this

```
import pandas as pd
import io, requests
import plotly.express as px

df_exte = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv"
        ).text
    )
)
df_exte["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_exte["date"])
df_exte[df_exte["location"] == "Cyprus"]
df_cyp = df_exte[df_exte["location"] == "Cyprus"]

fig = px.bar(
    df_cyp,
    x="date",
    y="total_cases",
    template="plotly_dark",
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.G10,
    labels=dict(date="April 2020 - October 2021", total_cases="Total Confirmed Cases"),
)

fig.update_layout(font_family="Rockwell")
fig.update_layout(title_text="CYPRUS TOTAL CASES", title_x=0.5)
fig["layout"]["title"]["font"] = dict(size=25)
fig.add_traces(
    px.line(
        df_cyp.loc[:, ["date", "total_cases"]].rolling(window=7, on="date").mean(),
        x="date",
        y="total_cases",
    ).data
)
```

[image]